# Fetching markers from controller to refresh map with gmaps4rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, gmaps4rails

I have an app with multiple marker in a Rails3 application using gmaps4rails.

The map is loaded initially with all the markers but I have a filter fields on the page which I would like the user to filter different things which are stored in the db for the markers.

How to I trigger the map to call the controller with the parameters which would return a new json object, which I would then put in Gmaps4Rails.replaceMarkers function?

I'm using JQuery so it would probably be best to trigger this behavior from Jquery code.

Regards,
Johann

Comment: What version of gmaps4rails do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set a event listener to those filter fields (or in a submit button), that then calls your_controller at the server via AJAX?

```
$("#yourSubmitButton").click(function() {
  $.getJSON('/get_markers.json', { filter: "value" }, function(json) {
    Gmaps.map.serviceObject.replaceMarkers(json);
  });
});
```

*Didn't test the code.*